# Load a configuration file optionally depending on the environment-Production or Test

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Using Spring Profile we can load a particular bean depending on the `@profile` annotation. Is it possible to load a particular configuration class depending on the environment. Actually the config class is annotated with specific annotations like `@EnableSwagger`, which gets loaded always. And have the requirement to load it optionally.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same scenario you're describing: I want to enable Swagger when a specific profile is enabled. Using a profile works without any problem:

```
@Profile("API")
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
```

Only when I use the API profile is the SwaggerConfig loaded.

Comment: Its what I wanted..Thanks.